# Down then Across in Crystal Report not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I want to show data in table like 2 columns. Por example:

```
1       6
2       7
3       8
4       9
5
```

So far, Across then Down with a 3.819 inches of width is working properly, but gives me the data like:

```
1       2
3       4
5       6
7       8
9
```

In Common Tab, Format with Multiple Columns is checked. I changed the width randomly and none of the cases was successful.

What else I can do?

This is the Report Design:

[image]

This is the details section:

[image: Details Section]

This is Across then Down (works fine):

[image]

This is Down then Across (not working properly):

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, with Down then Across gives me one column

Comment: How many fields do you display in your example?

Comment: 6 fields. Across then Down do it just as I want.

Comment: Can you explain at which field is each value related to? Maybe you can show us the Details Section Design of your report

Comment: @jambonick I edited the question! Please look at it. I changed the width randomly and none of the cases was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce the width by following:

**Details**, **Report** >> **Section Expert** >> **Details** >> **Layout** >> **Width**. I am also have problem to display multiple columns, but I **reduce the width** of details then the data is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found, Down and then Across works when it reaches the end of the page.
So increasing the vertical gap can trigger it sooner, but not really what would be desired because it wastes space...

[Increase Vertical gap is lamo, but show's behavior...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFEg4.png)